# How to allow an extension for two domains only?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've written a google chrome extension. It's okay and works now but I want the extension to be usebale only on two domains because it's written for these two websites only and is useless for others. There is a `context menu` only. For now it hasn't even popup, or action button in the top right corner (hidden by default). How can achieve this?

My current **manifest.json**:

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["scripts/jquery.min.js", "scripts/background.js"]
  },
  "name": "Export Entries",
  "description": "some descriptions here",
  "version": "1.0",

  "icons": {
    "16": "images/logo.png",
    "48": "images/logo.png",
    "128": "images/logo.png"
  },
  "permissions": ["downloads", "tabs", "contextMenus", "http://my-own-domain-accessed-via-ajax-for-creating-some-files-there.com/*"],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["*://allowed-domain1.com/*", "*://allowed-domain2.com/*"],
    "css": ["styles/style.css"],
    "js": ["scripts/jquery.min.js", "scripts/popup.js", "scripts/background.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "images/logo.png"
  ]
}
```

As I understand the extension cannot be disabled absolutely, its process will run in background again. But it's not a problem. I just want to not display the context menu item on other websites.

**background.js** creates the context menu item and handles its click event:

```js
function exportEntries(info, tab) {
  if (info['linkUrl'].indexOf('domain1.com/user/') > -1) {
    var user = info['linkUrl'].substr('27');
  } else {
    var user = null; // export all entries from this topic
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://my-own-domain-which-creates-the-file.eu/exportEntries/create.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      topic: tab.url,
      user: user
    }
  }).done(function(url) {
    forceDownload(url);
  });
}

function forceDownload(url) {
  var filename = url.replace(/^.*\/|\.[^.]*$/g, '');

  chrome.downloads.download({
      url: url,
      saveAs: true
    }, // options array
    function(id) {
      // callback function
    }
  );
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    'title': 'Export Entries',
    'contexts': ['link'],
    'onclick': function(info, tab) {
      exportEntries(info, tab);
    }
  });
});
```

**create.php** is on my own domain. It just gets the current page's URL and the user's nickname. Then export all entries from the given topic (i.e. page URL) for the given user, creates a file (.txt, .pdf etc.) and sends back url for downloading the file.

**popup.html**, **popup.js**, **css file** and other stuff is not used for now.

Comment: Can you show the relevant part of your code? I'm very curious about the contents of `scripts/background.js`, because you're including it twice (as a background script, and as a content script). I suspect that one of them (or even all content scripts) are misplaced. You can strip application logic, as long as the structure and Chrome API calls are still visible (`popup.js`, `background.js`).

Comment: @RobW, you're right, I removed `js` from `content_scripts` and it's working again. I just have other ideas to extend the extension (add popup with history etc.) and manifest is not cleaned from unneccessary stuff still. Do you have advices for the permissions?

Comment: Yes, I have already typed an answer, but since I didn't post it since it assumes that you've taken a certain approach. I don't want to play the guessing game, so can you share your code which creates the context menu? (Are you using `contextmenu` events or the `chrome.contextMenus` API? What happens if you click on the context menu entry?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove all of your content scripts, they're useless, because the [`chrome.contextMenus`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html) API can only be used on the background page.

To limit the context menu entry to certain domains, pecify the `documentUrlPatterns` key when you create the context menu using the [`chrome.contextMenus.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#method-create):

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    'title': 'Export Entries',
    'contexts': ['link'],
    'onclick': function(info, tab) {
        exportEntries(info, tab);
    },
    'documentUrlPatterns': [
        '*://allowed-domain1.com/*',
        '*://allowed-domain2.com/*'
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [content scripts documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html):

"If you want to inject the code only sometimes, use the permissions field instead, as described in [Programmatic injection](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi)."

So instead of

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
     "matches": [ "http://allowed-domain.com" ]
  }
],
```

use

```
permissions: [
  "tabs", "http://allowed-domain.com"
],
```